# Order rows of a data frame in some way *other* than ascending/descending

Tags: r, character, match

I have a data frame where one column is the "Frequency." The distinct values in this column are: Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly, Annually, and each value occurs more than once. I'd like to sort the data in exactly that order (rather than ascending/descending alphabetically) using the order function. Is there a way I can do that? Must I create some reference and use match?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good way to do this is with an ordered factor:

```
levels = c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Annually")
df = data.frame(Frequency=c("Daily", "Monthly", "Daily", "Annually"), number = 1:4)
df$Frequency = factor(df$Frequency, levels=levels)
df = df[order(df$Frequency),]
#       Frequency number
# 1     Daily      1
# 3     Daily      3
# 2   Monthly      2
# 4  Annually      4
```